# StackOverflowException in Partition function when N is greater then 10K

Tags: c#

**10K** works, **15K** results in `StackOverflowException`, when inside the `Partition` in the `QuickSort`.

**My MAIN:**

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int N = 15000;
            const bool M_ORDERED = true;
            Random random = new Random();

            int[] list = (M_ORDERED) ? Enumerable.Range(1, N).ToArray() : Enumerable.Range(1, N).OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToArray();

            // Capture current time
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            QuickSort.Sort(list, N);
            watch.Stop();
            double time = (double)watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0;

            String output = String.Format("Size: {0}, Elapsed time: {1:F2} sec", N, time);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

**QuickSort.cs**

```
class QuickSort
{
    public static void Sort(int[] a, int n) 
    {
        InternalSort(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
    }

    private static void InternalSort(int[] a, int low, int high) 
    {
        if (high <= low)
            return;

        int j = Partition(ref a, low, high);
        InternalSort(a, low, j - 1);
        InternalSort(a, j + 1, high);
    }

    private static int Partition(ref int[] a, int left, int right) 
    {
        int pivot = a[left];
        while (true)
        {
            while(a[left] < pivot)
                left++;

            while(a[right] > pivot)
                right--;

            if(left < right)
            {
                int temp = a[right];
                a[right] = a[left];
                a[left] = temp;
            } else
            {
                return right;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a quicksort without recursion and forget this problem.

Comment: Well, I want to do it with Recursion.

Comment: You have one megabyte for your stack. If you use more, you get this Exception. Change this is not a trivial task. Non recursive version works perflectly and without the stackoverflow exception problem. Why you need the recursion?

Comment: @Victor 4MB on a 64-bit system ;)

Comment: @jalsh thanks for pointing. That may give him more margin (if currently is in 32 bits system) before the exception, but in the end... the exception will occur.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to deal with this problem is to only recurse on the shorter sub-partition and loop on the longer one.

So instead of

```
private static void InternalSort(int[] a, int low, int high) 
{
    if (high <= low)
        return;

    int j = Partition(ref a, low, high);
    InternalSort(a, low, j - 1);
    InternalSort(a, j + 1, high);
}
```

you do

```
private static void InternalSort(int[] a, int low, int high) 
{
  while (true) {
    if (high <= low)
        return;

    int j = Partition(ref a, low, high);

    if (((j - 1) - low) < (high - (j + 1))) {
      InternalSort(a, low, j - 1);
      low = j + 1;
    }
    else {
      InternalSort(a, j + 1, high);
      high = j - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

This ensures that the partition that you recurse on will be at most half the size of the original at each level. This means, for example, that any 1,000,000 element array can be sorted with a maximum recursive call depth of around 20.